# Basic Password Generator - How to get different rand(number) when is called

Tags: c++, random, std

The output now is HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. What I would like the program to do is randomNum to have a different value each time it goes through the loop. so it would be like AacCEe... And goes on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "You'r PW is: \t" << endl;
    char abc [] {'A', 'a', 'B' ,'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k'};
    int randomNum =  rand() % 22;

    for(int i = 0; i <20; i++){
        cout << abc[randomNum];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `rand()` family of functions to generate anything that will actually be used as a password. On Linux use `/dev/random` or `CryptGenRandom` on Windows and please massively expand your alphabet of output characters.

Comment: Thanks, btw I just was testing around with the characters. Why shouldn't I use rand()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Initialized randomNum before you loop

```
int randomNum =  rand() % 22;
```

You should change your code to

```
    int randomNum;
    for(int i = 0; i <20; i++)
    {
        randomNum =  rand() % 22;
        cout << abc[randomNum];
    }
```

This should work.

Currently randomNum gets only one value and you use that value throughout your loop without the value changing.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop your printing the same character 20 times effectively, what you intended I suppose is randomly select 20 different characters. Look into my inlined comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "You'r PW is: \t" << endl;
    char abc [] {'A', 'a', 'B' ,'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k'};    

    for(int i = 0; i <20; i++){
        cout << abc[rand() % 22]; // look here
    }
}
```